# Google Cloud Sql Second Generation, error "mysql has gone away"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to use the new `CloudSQL` second generation with my `Magento` demo store hosted also on Google Cloud.
Since i'm already a usual `CloudSQL` customer, I think I have setup authorization and other stuff correctly.

The problem I have is that even a simple import does not complete and I receive "mysql has gone away" after 2/3 seconds that import has started.

what can it be? anyone with the second generation cloud sql has this issue?

In the logging system i see this error

```
 [Warning] User 'root'@'%' was assigned access 0x1fffffff but was allowed to have only 0x1fff7dff.
```

this is the only error i receive

Comment: Can you check the Logs section of Developer Console? From there you should be able to select "Cloud SQL" and then the instance you are having issues with and see the mysql server errors (if any).

Comment: hi, i have added the output of the log in my question. thx

Comment: Are you performing an import from Developer Console or using another tool? Are you able to connect to the database manually and run a simple SQL query e.g. "select 1;"?

Comment: i'm connecting via mysql client (mysql, percona, mariadb same results, and i run a simple    "mysql -hxxx -uxxx -pxxx my_db < my_file.sql" directly from my instance in same region. i'm able to log in, see the mysql cli and create a new db. as soon as i start import, it fails in couple seconds

Comment: Can you drop an e-mail to cloud-sql@google.com with your instance and project name? We can take a closer look.

Comment: hello @laixer thank you for the comment. fact is after a couple of hours of try and fail, i have deleted the instance. soon i will recreate one and try to import again the same file, if i will have issues, i will update this question. thank you

Comment: Hi @x86fantini did you resolve this problem? Im having the same issue.